# Делаю telegram бот через pytelegramborapi не получается принять фото и сохранить на компьютер

Tags: python-3.x, изображения, telebot, qrcode, photo

```
import telebot
import qrcode
import cv2
import PIL


bot=telebot.TeleBot('')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo','text'])

def f(message):
    if message.text:
        img = qrcode.make(message.text)
        type(img)
        img.save('qrcode.png')
        sti=open('qrcode.png', 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, sti)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Это qrcode с вашим сообщением: '+ message.text)
    if message.photo:
        print(message.jpg)
```

если отправляю сообщение с фотографией выводится строки, возможно ли из этих строк сделать фото и сохранить на компьютер с возможностью дальнейшего использования?

Answer (score 0):

```
            try:
            file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)
            downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
            src = 'C:/Users/KOLYA/PycharmProjects/k ege/' + '1.png'
            with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
                new_file.write(downloaded_file)
```

Нашел самостоятельно эта конструкция идеально сохраняет фото